# Composition of academic faculty over time: Fixed-term/freelancer vs regular/tenured

Tags: university, academic-history, adjunct-faculty, non-tenure

A friend of mine, who's still in academia but not in academia-studies, asked me for help in understanding the prevalence of non-regular employment of faculty in universities over time. It's been a decade since my union days, and even back then I was mostly concerned with local affairs, i.e. Israeli universities. What we're after is a chart, or a table, of the fraction of (senior) faculty members in universities, over time, who are employed precariously: Fixed-term contracts, adjuncts, inferior/secondary tracks, and other such non-regular employment. I need data for one of the following region of the world: The entire world; the US; the EU; Europe (i.e. regardless of EU membership).

The definition of what constitutes precarious employment is not that critical, since I care about the trend. It just has to be explicit and consistent over the course of time, so that I'm comparing apples with apples, sort of.

Answer (score 3):

An older [comprehensive report from Boston University](https://www.bu.edu/ntt/) (2010) has this chart about the US:

[image]

as part of an [Appendix of charts and stats](https://www.bu.edu/ntt/appendices/appendix-a/).

In 2015, the American Association of University Professors (AAUP) published this chart:

[image]

But I encourage you all to post an answer with more recent data!

Comment: The AAUP's annual reports include information on the long-term increase in the percentage of faculty that are not in tenure/tenure-track positions.  See the most recent report: https://www.aaup.org/report/annual-report-economic-status-profession-2020-21